# Tools for mass file delete

Tags: windows, file-management

We have a challenge in deleting circa X million files that meet a certain criteria - specifically must be over 90 days old and exclude certain file formats. To date, we've been using a multi-threaded powershell script which is good but still not as fast as we need as our ingest processes are creating new files at a very high rate. Does anyone have any practical applications they can recommend?

Comment: Just a note: The file system in use plays a role in this as well. Some file systems are better suited for such tasks than others.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, were definitely conscious there's a limit there however are hoping there's some clever tools out there that someone uses. Bonus points of course would be an app would presumably be a bit more feature-rich and save us having to rely on efficient coding.

Comment: From mentioning Powershell, I assume the tool should be for Windows? Any price margins? License considerations?

Comment: It seems to me that the creation of new files is hardly relevant to the problem if deleting only considers files older than 90 days. Creating files should take longer than deleting files. I'm not sure whether any tool could solve this. The bottleneck is probably in disk performance.

Comment: Do you want to do this manually, or must it be automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record we ended up sticking with the powershell method. Tests we were able to run with some off-the-shelf products weren't really demonstrating any big improvements. Thanks for the feedback.
Adding link as requested..
http://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-functions-to-delete-old-files-and-empty-directories/

Comment: Oh I can't take credit for the script. We basically customised this gentleman's excellent script :)
http://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-functions-to-delete-old-files-and-empty-directories/

Comment: Please include that link into your answer, thanks :-)

Comment: Fele free to accept your own answer, as this might help others in future.

Comment: Hm... for folks who can't or for whatever reason are unwilling to use or customize that script, it would be nice to hear what off-the-shelf products you evaluated (possibly as a separate answer or answers).